# Android Studio Selecting Tab shortcut on MacOS malfunction

Tags: macos, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

for last two years I've been using shortcut to switch between Tabs in Android Studio on Mac.
The Shortcut is CMD + Shift + `[` / `]`.

I always have Project Tool window opened on a side.

Today this shortcut started to malfunction. Previously I could switch between tabs as many times I wanted. Now, when I switch once, the main window "lose focus", and when I click it again, tabs in the Project Tool Window, start changing in the dropdown menu.

Is there anyway to restore previous behaviour? I don't remember changing any setting.

I've uploaded that behaviour in the quick video: https://streamable.com/z9t6qb

I keep clicking on the main window to gain focus and start performing shortcut. First time I click it, the tab changes, but then, options from dropdown menu in the Project Tool window change.

EDIT:
Two additional screenshots requested

[image]

[image]

Comment: Few ideas. 1) Please show a screenshot of your Project View panel options (the menu under the gear/cog icon). Could be one of them 2) Go to `Preferences | Keymap` in Android Studio and check what action those shortcuts got assigned to (show a screenshot). There is a button next to the local search field that allows locating actions by assigned shortcuts (whatever you will press in that popup). Maybe it's a different action now? (P.S. I'm not using Android Studio or Mac myself (Windows user using another JetBrains IDE))

Comment: @LazyOne I've added screenshots you've requested. I think everything is as it supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, nothing unusual as far as I can see. Will it work though if you use the alternate/2nd shortcut to switch between tabs (`^<-` and `^->`)? On your video, after switching to another tab ... the focus gets moved from the Editor to the Project View panel for some reason. And I'm thinking: maybe it's related to the shortcuts used (IDE or even OS).

Comment: Other than that: could be an IDE issue (this is not related to your case .. but just overall idea: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249360). I've tried searching on the Issue Tracker (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=project%20focus%20switch) but was unable to find any related tickets on first 3 pages (300 results). Possibly better keywords are needed.

Comment: Alternate shortcut did not work. I've tried creating my own, new for that and they behave in the similar fashion. I've even tried reinstalling the Android Studio and it still persists. The last one can actually indicate, that it's rather OS issue IMO.

Comment: Try this: 1) Locate the folder where Android Studio stores its preferences/plugins (see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#file_location and/or https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs -- it should use similar paths). 2) Backup and delete your IDE preferences + plugins (may include logs/indexes/caches foldersas well, for purity). 3) Now launch IDE -- it should start from scratch. See if that will help in any way. You can restore all or just some of the config files later from a backup (while IDE is closed of course)

Comment: P.S. Instead of dealing with actual files directly/manually (I prefer this way: safer) ... see if you have "File | Manage IDE Settings" menu -- here in PhpStorm it has actions for saving/restoring settings via jar/zip file & has an option to reset all to defaults.

Comment: If reset did not helped: try downloading any JetBrains IDE (trial version is fine) -- ideally IntelliJ IDEA as it's more close in functionality to Android Studio than any other. See if you can reproduce the same there. If you will see the same behaviour then it's not Android Studio specific issue and can be MacOS (although I would still file a ticket to the [IntelliJ IDEA Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) for devs/support team to look into it -- they should know more what that might be)

Comment: This is driving me NUTS! I've had this issue for the past three days and can't find a solution either.

Comment: Honestly I've stopped trying after two days. Every time I've stopped using Mac I turned it off completely instead of just putting to sleep and after a few days it started working again.. I have no idea what happend. Wish you the same.

Comment: This issue popped up in Android Studio Bumblebee too (macOS, M1 Pro MacBook Pro). Deleted and reinstalled, the issue is still there. Such a productivity killer, so annoying! Come on Google! This is not an RC or Canary or Beta build, this is supposed to be stable software! Test your sh*t before pushing it to production!

Answer (score 5):

This is apparently a known bug within the entire JetBrains IntelliJ/IDEA codebase that recently popped up, as documented here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-261595

It is currently marked as fixed, but the Android Studio team will need to get this change into Android Studio for it to be fixed there as well.

It's indeed very annoying as I see it happening as well.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed in the latest Android Studio beta version, Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Beta 3 (you can run this alongside the stable version of Android Studio).

You can download this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview).